# Rails 6 polymorphic associations joins - PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, psql

I want calculate of unread user messages from multi-user chat system. I've got below models with polymorphic associations:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :conversations, as: :sendable
  has_many :conversations, as: :recipientable
end

class Message < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :conversation
  belongs_to :messageable, polymorphic: true

  scope :unread, ->(user) { where('messageable_id != ? AND read = ?', user.id, false) }
end

class Conversation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :sendable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :recipientable, polymorphic: true
  has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy
end
```

To calculate unread messages I'm using below query:

```
Conversation.where(sendable: current_user).map do |conversation|
  conversation.unread_message_count(current_user) unless conversation.unread_message_count(current_user).zero?
end
```

But it produces me N+1 query which I want to get rid of by new query:

```
Conversation.select('conversations.*', 'COUNT(messages.*) AS unread_message_count')
            .preload(:sendable, :messages)
            .where(sendable: current_user, messages: { read: false })
            .group(:id)
```

But I'm getting an error:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "messages")
> LINE 1: SELECT conversations.*, COUNT(messages.*) AS unread_message_...

How to fix this or replace it by pure SQL query?

Comment: why not use `joins`?

Comment: Because joins won't worked for polymorphic associations

Comment: Messages can be a join because the association between conversation and messages is not polymorphic. e.g. `Conversation.joins(:messages).select('conversations.*', 'COUNT(messages.*) AS unread_message_count').where(sendable: current_user, messages: { read: false }).group(:id)` will work fine. That being said I have no idea why Conversation has those polymorphic relationships. Are there entities other than `User` that are sendable or recipientable?

Comment: Your User model is not going to work as `conversations` will only be `as: :recipientable` because you cannot define the same association name twice so the last one interpreted will be the only one.

Comment: It has to be polymorphic because it's a part of multi user messaging system like here - https://medium.com/@batuhanwilhelm/rails-5-messaging-system-no-gem-b4a52bc4ebb4 . The join you showed return `<ActiveRecord::Relation` instead of number of unread messages.